# Cannot retrieve data to send on email with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller

I had a similar problem before but it was fixed but even after getting to know how its done this is very confusing. So I have a function written on a controller which receives data from MySQL database and sends an email using code igniter functions. So here is the controller code

```
 public function sendEmailToNewBorrower() {
    //fetch tha data from the database 
        $this->load->model('payment_plan');
        $foo = $this->payment_plan->getInfoToNotifyBorrowerForNewLoan();
        $result = json_decode(json_encode($foo), true);

        $this->load->library('email'/*, $config*/);
        $this->email->from('info@loaners.club', 'Loaners CLub');
        $this->email->to($result->Email);
        $this->email->subject('Consumer Credit Information');
        //$msg = $this->load->view('mypayment_view', '', true);
        $name = ($result->Fullname);
        $TotalAmountOfLoan = ($result->capital_payment); 
        $BorrowedAmount = ($result->borrowed_amount);
        $LCcomission = ($result->amount_invoiced);
        $Interest = ($result->interest_payment);
        $Cur = ($result->Abbreviation);
        $duedate = ($result->duedate);
        $installment = ($result->instalmentnbr);
        $BorrowerInterest = ($result->Interest);
        $overdueInterest = ($result->overdue_interest);
        $APR = ($result->total_payment);
        $BorrowingPeriod = ($result->Loantime);
        $msg1 =('https://apps.facebook.com/jussintestins/index.php'); 
        $this->email->message(
            'Hello! '.$name."\n"."\n"
            .'You have  a loan and we would like you to know all information about your loan. '."\n"."\n"."\n"
            .'Loan information'."\n"."\n"

            .'Total Borrowed Amount:  '.$cur.' '.$BorrowedAmount.'.'."\n"
            .'Loaners Club Comission: '.$cur.' '.$LCcomission.'.'."\n"
            .'Total Payment :  '.$cur.' '.$TotalAmountOfLoan.'.'."\n"
            .'Installments :'.$installment.'.'."\n"
            .'Interest Rate :'.$BorrowerInterest.'%.'."\n"
            .'Interest Paid :'.$Interest.'%.'."\n"
            .'Over due payment interest :'.$overdueInterest.'%.'."\n"
            .'Your borrowing period: '.$BorrowingPeriod.'.'."\n"

                ."\n"."\n"
            .'You have the right to withdraw the money'."\n"
            .'You can click this link to pay your loan.'.'Something heere'.'.'."\n"."\n"."\n"
            .'Thank you for using Loaners Club and we would like you to see all our other offers here '.$msg1."\n"."\n"
            .'For more information contact info@loanersclub.com  '
            ."\n"
            ."\n"
            .'Have a great day! Loaners Club'
          );  
    $returnvalue = $this->email->send();
  if(!$returnvalue) {
       alert("email failed to send");
    } else {
     $data=array('notified_borrower'=>current_time,'current_time'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
     $this->db->update('payment_plan', $data);
       }
}
```

So when I debug the program it shows that I do get data from the database.
[image]
but when I check the $result it shows me this.
[image]

So right now I do not know why this is happening as I get no information stored there but I do get an error saying cannot read length. And one more thing is that the update part at the end also doesn't update.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reviewed your function and corrected it. please check, and take note of the comments i left.

```
public function sendEmailToNewBorrower() {
    //fetch tha data from the database
    $this->load->model('payment_plan');
    $foo = $this->payment_plan->getInfoToNotifyBorrowerForNewLoan();
    /**
     * If @foo is json
     * json_decode($foo); will return an Object. json_decode($foo, true) will return an array
     */
    //$result = json_decode($foo);
    $result = json_decode(json_encode($foo[0]), true);

    $this->load->library('email'/*, $config*/); //Why is the $config off here? make sure you have a proper config loaded for your email library
    $this->email->from('info@loaners.club', 'Loaners CLub');
    $this->email->to($result->Email);
    $this->email->subject('Consumer Credit Information');
    //$msg = $this->load->view('mypayment_view', '', true);
    $name               = $result['Fullname'];
    $TotalAmountOfLoan  = $result['capital_payment'];
    $BorrowedAmount     = $result['borrowed_amount'];
    $LCcomission        = $result['amount_invoiced'];
    $Interest           = $result['interest_payment'];
    $Cur                = $result['Abbreviation'];
    $duedate            = $result['duedate'];
    $installment        = $result['instalmentnbr'];
    $BorrowerInterest   = $result['Interest'];
    $overdueInterest    = $result['overdue_interest'];
    $APR                = $result['total_payment'];
    $BorrowingPeriod    = $result['Loantime'];

    $msg1 =('https://apps.facebook.com/jussintestins/index.php');
    $this->email->message(
        'Hello! '.$name."\n"."\n"
        .'You have  a loan and we would like you to know all information about your loan. '."\n"."\n"."\n"
        .'Loan information'."\n"."\n"
        //You are trying to add a variable named $Cur as $cur. changed it to $Cur..
        .'Total Borrowed Amount:  '.$Cur.' '.$BorrowedAmount.'.'."\n"
        .'Loaners Club Comission: '.$Cur.' '.$LCcomission.'.'."\n"
        .'Total Payment :  '.$Cur.' '.$TotalAmountOfLoan.'.'."\n"
        .'Installments :'.$installment.'.'."\n"
        .'Interest Rate :'.$BorrowerInterest.'%.'."\n"
        .'Interest Paid :'.$Interest.'%.'."\n"
        .'Over due payment interest :'.$overdueInterest.'%.'."\n"
        .'Your borrowing period: '.$BorrowingPeriod.'.'."\n"

        ."\n"."\n"
        .'You have the right to withdraw the money'."\n"
        .'You can click this link to pay your loan.'.'Something heere'.'.'."\n"."\n"."\n"
        .'Thank you for using Loaners Club and we would like you to see all our other offers here '.$msg1."\n"."\n"
        .'For more information contact info@loanersclub.com  '
        ."\n"
        ."\n"
        .'Have a great day! Loaners Club'
    );
    $returnvalue = $this->email->send();
    if(!$returnvalue) {
        alert("email failed to send");
    } else {
        $data=array('notified_borrower'=>current_time,'current_time'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $this->db->update('payment_plan', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this function $result = json_decode($foo); the result says its null and the foo says it has the array , so yea its still not working.

Comment: and shouldnt it be ($foo, true) since its returning an array from db anyways right ?

Comment: can you do print_r on the $foo and post the result please

Comment: I put the error that comes to the screen on the top as a picture

Comment: @Farhana can you give me Teamviewer access, it is unclear what's going on

Comment: Hey I dont have team viewer but I tried a different way writing it like this $result = json_decode(json_encode($foo[0]), true); and then the $result->Fullname shows that it has a string(masnad) but when I click beside it on the $name , it shows null

Comment: @Farhana because you don't need to wrap the result in curly braces. see my new answer (updated)

Comment: the $name is still null after doing that :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98082/discussion-between-ilan-hasanov-and-farhana).

Answer (score 0):

As per your given image  `$foo` is array not json because json_decode  is  already  given array so not need `json_decode($foo);` you can directly use like below

```
$foo = $this->payment_plan->getInfoToNotifyBorrowerForNewLoan();
$result = json_decode($foo);
```

Comment: I did that , but now I get the $name and all other values with null

Comment: and i get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (10:41:23:735 | error, javascript)

Comment: Hello , You need to add like    $result[0]->Fullname;

Comment: $result[0] in all the places ?